# MSSQL query with join and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've the following tables

```
Candidates
Id  Name  PicId
 1  Tom   NULL
 2  James 1
 3  Bob   NULL
 4  Manny 2

Attachments
Id  Name
 1  One.jpg
 2  Two.doc
 3  Three.rtf

The join table AttachmentCandidate
CandidateId  AttachmentId
    3             1
    3             2
    4             3
```

So from the above tables it shows that a candidate's 'PicId' is nullable & one candidate can have 0 or many attachments.

Now the query what I wish to create is the one which should return me Candidate's Name, PicId, & Attachment Name, but I don't want the candidates who neither have a PicId nor any Attachments.

I was able to achieve it with a subquery. Is there any better way it can be done??

```
SELECT r.cname,r.picId,r.attName FROM 
(SELECT Candidates.Name as cname,
Candidates.PicId as picId, 
Attachments.Name as attName
FROM Candidates LEFT JOIN AttachmentCandidate
ON Candidates.Id = AttachmentCandidate.CandidateId
LEFT JOIN Attachments
ON AttachmentCandidate.AttachmentId = Attachments.Id) as r
WHERE (r.picId IS NOT NULL OR r.attName IS NOT NULL)

Result
cname   picId  attName
James   1      NULL
Bob     NULL   One.jpg
Bob     NULL   Two.doc
Manny   3      Three.rtf
```

And the candidate 'Tom' not is present in the result since he doesn't have a picId nor any attachments

Answer (score 1):

My only real comment to make is that the subquery is irrelevant. You can achieve the same result without it.

---

When specifying your column aliases in the outer query. There is no need for you to use `AS picid` as the column is already called `picid`.

---

You could also use table aliases as well to shorten some of the statements. I personally prefer to see aliases than fully qualified table names. Assuming everyone sticks to a naming convention of course. My normal rule of thumb is that each capital letter of the table becomes the alias.

---

Also, as we can remove the subquery, we can change the `WHERE` clause so it is no longer filtering out the attachment name but instead the PK (`WHERE a.Id IS NOT NULL`).

---

For the columns being returned, can we make them more explicit? i.e. CandidateName instead of CName, etc.

Here is the modified version of your query using the changes above:

```
SELECT
     c.Name     AS CandidateName
    ,c.picid    AS PicId
    ,a.Name     AS AttachmentName
FROM Candidates c
LEFT JOIN AttachmentCandidate ac ON c.Id = ac.CandidateId
LEFT JOIN Attachments a ON ac.AttachmentId = a.Id
WHERE c.picid IS NOT NULL
OR a.Id IS NOT NULL
```

---

I'm not sure whether the formatting is just bad when you created your question or whether your SQL query is like that? If so, it's badly formatted and difficult to read. I try and break up each part of the query into separate segments so it's easy to read and maintain by others:

```
SELECT
     r.cname
    ,r.PicId
    ,r.attName
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Candidates.Name     AS cname
        ,Candidates.PicId   AS picid
        ,Attachments.Name   AS attname
    FROM Candidates
    LEFT JOIN AttachmentCandidate ON Candidates.Id = AttachmentCandidate.CandidateId
    LEFT JOIN Attachments ON AttachmentCandidate.AttachmentId = Attachments.Id
) AS r
WHERE (r.PicId IS NOT NULL OR r.attName IS NOT NULL)
```

As you requested an alternative, i'll give you one. Essentially it's pretty much the reverse of what you're doing. I'm gathering all of the candidates with attachments first and then I `RIGHT JOIN` back onto the candidates table and filter out the ones without a PicId.

```
SELECT
    c.Name      AS CandidateName
    ,c.PicId    AS PicId
    ,a.Name     AS AttachmentName
FROM AttachmentCandidate ac
INNER JOIN Attachments a ON a.Id = ac.AttachmentId
RIGHT JOIN Candidates c ON c.Id = ac.CandidateId
WHERE c.picid IS NOT NULL
OR a.Id IS NOT NULL
```